# How to use OneVsRestClassifier with SVC for multilabel problems?

Tags: svm, scikit-learn

I'm using OneVsRestClassifier for multilabel classification. It works with LinearSVC, but when I apply it to SVC, the following error appears:

```
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(class_weight='balanced'))
classifier.fit(X1, y1)
y2 = classifier.predict(X2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 219, in predict
  return predict_ovr(self.estimators_, self.label_binarizer_, X)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 93, in predict_ovr
  Y = np.array([_predict_binary(e, X) for e in estimators])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 66, in _predict_binary
  score = estimator.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 490, in predict_proba
  "probability estimates must be enabled to use this method")
NotImplementedError: probability estimates must be enabled to use this method</code>
```

Does anybody know what is it?

Comment: t looks like you are trying to obtain probabilistic output but you forgot to include probability estimates when training the models. Can you post the training commands?

Comment: It's very straightforward:

`classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(class_weight='auto'));
classifier.fit(X1, y1);
y2 = classifier.predict(X2)`
The error occurs while predicting (in the last line). The same code works for LinearSVC, but does not for SVC, so that surprises me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1946). The `OneVsRestClassifier` calls the `predict_proba` method when it finds one, but the one on `SVC` does not actually work unless you construct it with `probability=True` to get [Platt scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15111408/166749) (which I don't actually encourage).

The reason that it works for `LinearSVC` is that that class does not have a `predict_proba`, so OvR backs off to the `decision_function` method.

Comment: Has this been fixed yet? If not is there a temporary fix to get this to work?

Comment: I'm still seeing the issue in version 0.14.1. My code is identical to OP's except I'm using a Pipeline with SelectKBest preceding the SVC().

Comment: @willwest Strange. But in any case, it works fine in 0.15b1, the current beta.