# sklearn svm non integer outputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

i've been trying to find this information around and couldnt found any help.
What i want to do is get a float number as output from sklearn svm in order to work as input for a sub classifier.

Is it possible to get output from svm like 0,89898 instead of 1, given that a class is more closely to be classified as 1?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Platt scaling](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.1639) can help to achieve what you want. It fits a logistic sigmoid curve on top of the output of SVM in a post-hoc fashion.

To do this in sklearn, you'll need to fit your SVM with probability parameter set to True. Then, you can use the fitted model's predict_proba() method to get a floating point output. More documentations can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html). You'll also find related discussions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111408/how-does-sklearn-svm-svcs-function-predict-proba-work-internally/15112563#15112563) thread.