# Enable Probability Estimates in scikit.smv.SVC based on LIBSVM

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

In LIBSVM, the `-b` flag in `svmtrain`is used to enable training a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates. To get the corresponding results for the test set, we also set the `-b` results in `svmpredict`

For example, in MATLAB, we would write the following code to train and test with probability estimates enabled:

```
model = svmtrain(train_labels, train_set, '-b 1')
[result, accuracy, prob] = svmpredict(test_labels, test_set, '-b 1')
```

However, when initializing the SVC in the scikit-learn library, we can only set the `-b` flag when training, which would be the same as setting the `-b` flag on `svmtrain`:

```
clf = scikit.svm.SVC(probability=True)
```

For testing in scikit-learn, I am using `clf.predict(test_set)` to get the classes. However, this yields different results then when I use `svmpredict` with `-b 1` flag.

What is the equivalent in scikit-learn svm for setting the `-b` flag during testing with `svmpredict`?

Comment: Yes, its expected because predict() doesnt use the probability. Its mentioned in the docs here: scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#scores-and-probabilities

Answer (score -1):

Scikit-learn doesn't use a flag to predict the probabilities of a classifier, there's an additional function available called `.predict_proba`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).

The probabilities are determined using [Platt scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling), which is a way to combine arbitrary outputs from a classifier into class probabilities.

See also the answer here: [How does sklearn.svm.svc's function predict_proba() work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111408/how-does-sklearn-svm-svcs-function-predict-proba-work-internally)