# How does sklearn's MLP predict_proba function work internally?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, probability, mlp

I am trying to understand how [`sklearn`'s MLP Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) retrieves its results for its `predict_proba` function.

The website simply lists:

> Probability estimates

While many others, such as [logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba), have more detailed answers:
Probability estimates.

The returned estimates for all classes are ordered by the label of classes.

> For a multi_class problem, if multi_class is set to be “multinomial”
>   the softmax function is used to find the predicted probability of each
>   class. Else use a one-vs-rest approach, i.e calculate the probability
>   of each class assuming it to be positive using the logistic function.
>   and normalize these values across all the classes.

Other model types, too, have more detail. Take for example a [support vector machine classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

And there is also [this very nice Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111408/how-does-sklearn-svm-svcs-function-predict-proba-work-internally) which explains it in depth.

> Compute probabilities of possible outcomes for samples in X.
>
> The model need to have probability information computed at training
>   time: fit with attribute probability set to True.

**Other Examples**

[Random Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba):

> Predict class probabilities for X.
>
> The predicted class probabilities of an input sample are computed as
>   the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The
>   class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the
>   same class in a leaf.

[Gaussian Process Classifier:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier)

I am looking to understand the same thing as the above post, but for the `MLPClassifier`. How does the `MLPClassifier` work internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking within the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py), i found:

```
def _initialize(self, y, layer_units):

    # set all attributes, allocate weights etc for first call
    # Initialize parameters
    self.n_iter_ = 0
    self.t_ = 0
    self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]

    # Compute the number of layers
    self.n_layers_ = len(layer_units)

    # Output for regression
    if not is_classifier(self):
        self.out_activation_ = 'identity'
    # Output for multi class
    elif self._label_binarizer.y_type_ == 'multiclass':
        self.out_activation_ = 'softmax'
    # Output for binary class and multi-label
    else:
        self.out_activation_ = 'logistic'
```

It seems that MLP Classifier uses a logistic function for binary classification and a softmax function for multi-label classification in order to build the output layer. This suggests that the output of the net is a probability vector, based on which the net deduces predictions.

If I look to the `predict_proba` method:

```
def predict_proba(self, X):
    """Probability estimates.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
        The input data.
    Returns
    -------
    y_prob : ndarray of shape (n_samples, n_classes)
        The predicted probability of the sample for each class in the
        model, where classes are ordered as they are in `self.classes_`.
    """
    check_is_fitted(self)
    y_pred = self._predict(X)

    if self.n_outputs_ == 1:
        y_pred = y_pred.ravel()

    if y_pred.ndim == 1:
        return np.vstack([1 - y_pred, y_pred]).T
    else:
        return y_pred
```

That confirms the action of a softmax or a logistic as activation function for the output layer in order to have a probability vector.

Hoping this can help you.